# Regex expression to find words containing exactly 2 vowels

Tags: regex

I need a regex expression to find only words which contain exactly two vowels
I got this so far

```
^\w*[aeiouy]\w*[aeiouy]\w*(?!([aeiouy]+))
```

but it finds words with 2 **or more**. Any ideas?

Comment: `\w` will match any word character, which includes `aeiouy`.

Answer (score 1):

`/\b[^aeiouy\s]*?([aeiouy][^aeiouy\s]*){2}\b/gi` should work.

- `\b` begin at a word boundary
- `[^aeiouy\s]*?` 0 or more of anything that isn't a vowel or space
- `([aeiouy][^aeiouy\s]*){2}` exactly 2 instances of a vowel followed by zero or more non-vowels
- `\b` end at a word boundary

Comment: Why use `\b` inside `[...]`? Do you know what `\b` means inside a character class? A backspace char (unless it is a POSIX pattern, it is treated as a ``\`` and `b` chars there).

Comment: regexr uses JS  or PCRE flavor. Then, `\b` is a backspace char, why do you think it must be in the pattern?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew try it in your console if you like, it does not interpret it as a ` \\` and a `b`. The idea was to rule out non-word characters, but in practice if the text that's being tested is properly formatted, that case will never occur anyway. I'll take it out as it's most likely unnecessary. If needs be, OP can manually add in `,.-/\\` etc for any other characters that need to be accounted for

Comment: I have already written thay in *this* case, `[\b]` matches a backspace char. Next, `[^aeiouy\s]` matches *any  char* other than `a`, `e`...whitespace chars. It will grab much more than a word. OP needs to find *words*.... However, what is a word for OP is not clear, as the original pattern starts with `^`. Probably, OP means a *whole string*, then your answer may work.

Comment: Why are you so sure OP uses it in JavaScript code and not in some R code? If something works at  regexr.com, it does not mean it will work in the target environment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why are you so sure he doesn't? Just because it doesn't work in your preferred version of code doesn't make it wrong. If it doesn't suit his needs, let him say so rather than blowing up the comments with useless chatter.

Answer (score 0):

```
\b[^aeiouAEIOU\s\d]*[aeiouAEIOU][^aeiou\s\d]*[aeiou][^aeiou\s\d]*\b
```

- `[^aeiouAEIOU\s\d]*` matches all consonants (may or may not be in Upper Case) 0 or more times (the start of a word may or may not be a vowel)
- `[aeiouAEIOU]` matches a single character that is a vowel
- `[^aeiou\s\d]*` matches all consonants 0 or more times
- `[aeiou]` matches a single character that is a vowel
- `[^aeiou\s\d]*` matches 0 or more consonants

> If you wish to include **y** as well:
>
> ```
> \b[^aeiouAEIOU\s\d]*[aeiouyAEIOU][^aeiouy\s\d]*[aeiouy][^aeiouy\s\d]*\b
> ```
>
> **Note:** we are not adding **y** at the beginning sequence as words with the vowel y don't begin with y